# Sidekiq With Whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, whenever

I'm using whenever for schedule of job with sidekiq. Also, use `sidekiq-client-cli` gem, that is a command line client for sidekiq and allows the cron jobs to interact with sidekiq.

This my active job file :

```
# jobs/clone_record_job.rb

class CloneRecordJob < ActiveJob::Base
    queue_as :myapps

    def perform(*args)
      Core::Block.where(release_date: Date.today - 30.days).each do |block|
        new_block = Core::Block.new(block.attributes)
        new_block._id = BSON::ObjectId.new
        new_block.save
      end
    end
end
```

schedule file :

```
# config/schedule.rb
job_type :sidekiq, "cd :path && :environment_variable=:environment bundle exec sidekiq-client -q myapps push :task :output"

every 1.minute, :roles => [:app] do
    sidekiq "CloneRecordJob"
end
```

Sidekiq log :

```
2016-08-09T10:13:41.138Z 23668 TID-xvshg WARN: {"class":"CloneRecordJob","queue":"myapps","args":[],"retry":true,"jid":"98cb26a0dd7410a9be0f0200","created_at":1470737621.1380692,"enqueued_at":1470737621.1382036}
2016-08-09T10:13:41.141Z 23668 TID-xvshg WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `jid=' for #<CloneRecordJob:0x0000000715cc30>
```

Note :

I'm sure that job is work when to call from controller.

```
# example method
def my_action
  CloneRecordJob.perform_now
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloneRecordJob is an ActiveJob, not a Sidekiq::Worker.  You can't use sidekiq-client-cli with ActiveJobs.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've read some of wiki, and now I think I need a `Sidekiq::Worker` for my case, eg : `HardWorker` class